# Under what conditions is the solution to this system of ODE's bounded?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
    u_1'  \\
    u_2' 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1\\
    1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    u_1  \\
    u_2 
\end{bmatrix}
$

$u_1(0) = \alpha, u_2(0) = \beta,( \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R})$

Determine the set of values $\alpha,\beta$ for which the solution $u_1,u_2$ is bounded on the interval $(0,\infty)$

I have no idea where to start, I have no theorems at hand which can help me with this, so

I have let $u_2 = u$

and obtained the second order IVP

$u'' - u' - u = 0, u(0) = \alpha, u'(0) = \beta$.

Again, I have no tools at hand to help me deal with this?

You may have noticed the many rubbish posts from me on the subject of ODE's. As a side note, could someone recommend a decent source for ODE material?

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx, the characteristic polynomial yields $m_{1, 2} = \dfrac{1}{2} \left(1 \pm~\sqrt{5}\right)$. Can you now conclude what the ICs need to be for a bounded solution?

Comment: "I have no idea where to start" Fully solve the system, then deduce the initial conditions which yield bounded solutions.